# 3 tables or 1 table?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `domains` (
`domains_id` bigint(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`domains_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`domains_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `domains_actions` (
  `domains_actions_id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `domains_actions_selmgec` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `domains_id` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `domains_actions_member` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `domains_actions_date` date NOT NULL,
  `actions_id` int(2) NOT NULL
  `domains_actions_value` int(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`domains_actions_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `actions` (
  `actions_id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `actions_action` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`actions_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

So if I have read properly, I need an actions tables for the likes/new/social then this is linked into domains_actions.

Comment: How often do you join to one of these tables?  Are you hitting a performance ceiling?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you're trying to do with these, but they obviously have repeating data. You should consolidate into one table with a `type` column; perhaps using `ENUM`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `domains` (
  `domains_id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `domains_selmgec` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `domains_domain` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `domains_member` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `domains_date` date NOT NULL,
  `domains_type` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `type` ENUM('likes', 'new', 'social'),
  PRIMARY KEY (`domains_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

A more relational and normalized schema would look something like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `domain` (
  `id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `selmgec` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `domain` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `member` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `type` int(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `type` (
  `id` tinyint(1) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `domainType` (
  `domain_id` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `type_id` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`domain_id`, `type_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This design will allow you hold a single domain and assign it multiple types. You would need to change the engine to `InnoDb` and create foreign key constrains to enforce these types.

### [See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf16c/1)

Comment: I tend to prefer fewer cleaner tables that associate with a single idea or object type (a Domain in this example, as opposed to a LikedDomain).

Comment: @RichardBrown Depends on how large your table should be. With proper indexes it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: ok but say like each table had 1,000,000 results in? would this not be faster than the one table with 3,000,000 in?

Comment: @RichardBrown It would be negligible.

Comment: @RichardBrown See my update. This updated design will only require a single set of domains and you can create a relation for multiple types in `domainType`.

Comment: @njk see my updated first post, I already have a domains tables which is separate to store the domains I want!

Comment: @RichardBrown Then my updated design would have another table to hold URLs. You would then reference those from the `domain` table.

Comment: @njk see my update tables, I believe this is the best way, as the type field has different values depending on what is selected in the action field, i.e. action = like, type 1 = like, type 2 = ulike / action = new, type 1 = new, type 2 = old

Comment: @RichardBrown I would still recommend using a `type` table. This will decrease the overhead from having 3 records for each type. `JOIN`s generally perform faster.

Comment: I have edited my original tables. I believe this is what your telling me to do? should I get rid of domains_actions_value? and instead of having like values 1 or 2, just have like,unlike in the actions table?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing all of the details, I would create one table and then a `TypeId` column that references another table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `domains` (
  `domains_id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `domains_selmgec` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `domains_domain` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `domains_member` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `domains_date` date NOT NULL,
  `domains_type` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `type_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`domains_likes_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `types` (
  `type_id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type_name` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`type_id`)
) ;
```

Comment: @njk agreed, there are many ways to model this. And they are all probably better than using 3 identical tables. :)